# Running blazor as a service

Tags: service, blazor

I want to run my blazor app as a service using TopShelf but now that i have configured a service i lost all css. it does still use Startup as it is supposed to but it just doesnt load my css? is this just a problem with paths? or is it something else?

I havent made any changes to the Startup class.

my main:

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service(() => new Service(args));
                x.SetServiceName("Print");
                x.SetDescription("service");
                x.StartAutomaticallyDelayed();

            });

            Environment.ExitCode = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
        }
```

my Service:

```cs
        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Configuration.Settings settings = Program.initSettings();
            new Task(() => CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseStaticWebAssets()
                .UseUrls(settings.BaseAddress)
                .Build().Run()).Start();

            return true;
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
            });
            //.UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of trial and error i found it was a dumb mistake. I didn't change the properties of the css files to copy to output directory. Now my css is being loaded.